# How to convert this SQL query to Oracle. Is there any Tool

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I mostly work with SQL. I don't know how to convert this SQL query to Oracle. Can anyone tell me how to convert this below query?

```
    DECLARE @START_YEAR INT,@MONTH INT, @END_YR INT
    SELECT 
    @START_YEAR = 2010,
    @END_YR = 2010,
    @MONTH = 1

    WHILE ( @START_YEAR <= @END_YR)
    BEGIN
    WHILE ( @MONTH <= 12)
    BEGIN

    PRINT 'INSERT INTO dbo.Mem_TXN
               ([VALUE]
               ,[BEGIN_DATE]
               ,[END_DATE]
               ,[CREATED_BY]
               ,[CREATED_DATE]
               ,[MODIFIED_BY]
               ,[MODIFIED_DATE])
         VALUES
               (''RGLR'' 
               ,'''  + cast( Convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @START_YEAR - 1900, 0)))  AS varchar) + '''  
               ,''' + cast( Convert(date,DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH,     DATEADD(YEAR, @START_YEAR - 1900, -1))) AS VARCHAR) + '''
               ,''admin''
               ,' +FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')+ '
               ,''admin''
               ,' +FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')+ '
               ,0);
               '
    SET @MONTH = @MONTH + 1
    END
    SET @MONTH = 1
    SET @START_YEAR = @START_YEAR + 1
    END
```

This SQL query for used to generate the SQL **INPUT** statement.

When I tried to manually convert this SQL query, I got a syntax error. Is it possible to convert the SQL query using a converter tool because I don't have enough time to learn Oracle in order to modify this SQL query?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the eexpected result, please?

Comment: What did you try so far and what is the issue with your current approach? SO is not a free coding service

Comment: I need an input statement with the value of the begin date being every month's first date and the value of the end date being every month's last date for a given range of years.

Comment: SQL is a language standard, so I guess you mean you're converting from Microsoft SQL Server's dialect of SQL to Oracle's dialect of SQL. Your generated insert statements [look odd](https://dbfiddle.uk/4Cq5Hmi_) - you specify 7 column names but 8 values, some dates/datetimes are quoted strings, other are unquoted and have invalid month numbers. Are you trying to generate exactly that text, or insert statements that would be valid in Oracle - target table structure might help; or do you actually want to perform the inserts rather than creating a script to run later? How far have you got with it?

Comment: @astentx Sorry about that. I'm not asking anyone to write this code in Oracle. I'm wondering if there are any tools available to convert SQL code to ORACLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with Oracle Sql Developer, and the code like this:

```
DECLARE
    v_START_YEAR NUMBER(10);
    v_MONTH NUMBER(10);
    v_END_YR NUMBER(10);
    v_QUERY NVARCHAR2(2000);
    v_DATENOW NVARCHAR2(20);
    v_DATEFST NVARCHAR2(15);
    v_DATELST NVARCHAR2(15);
    v_DATECHAR NVARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
    v_START_YEAR := 2010;
    v_END_YR := 2010;
    v_MONTH := 1;
   
    SELECT to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi') INTO v_DATENOW FROM dual;

    WHILE  v_START_YEAR <= v_END_YR
    LOOP
        WHILE ( v_MONTH <= 12)
        LOOP
            --date char
            v_DATECHAR := ''||to_char(v_START_YEAR)||'-'||to_char(v_MONTH)||'-01';
           
            --first date
            select to_char(TRUNC(TO_DATE(v_DATECHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') into v_DATEFST from dual;
            -- last date
            select to_char(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(v_DATECHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),0)), 'yyyy-MM-dd') into v_DATELST from dual;
           
            v_QUERY := 'INSERT INTO Mem_TXN
                        (VALUE,
                        BEGIN_DATE,
                        END_DATE,
                        CREATED_BY,
                        CREATED_DATE,
                        MODIFIED_BY,
                        MODIFIED_DATE)
                        VALUES (
                            ''RGLR'',
                            '|| v_DATEFST ||',
                            '|| v_DATELST ||',
                            ''admin'',
                            '|| v_DATENOW ||',
                            ''admin'',
                            '|| v_DATENOW ||',
                            0
                        )';
               
            dbms_output.put_line(v_QUERY);
           
        v_MONTH := v_MONTH + 1;
        END LOOP;
        v_MONTH := 1;
        v_START_YEAR := v_START_YEAR + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then result like this:
[view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4556.png)

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it did not convert properly.

Comment: I have revised this answer, and please try

Answer (score 0):

Here's an insert statement that will do what you need:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.men_txn ("VALUE", begin_date, end_date, created_by, created_date, modified_by, modified_date)
WITH dts AS (SELECT add_months(to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), LEVEL - 1) dt
             FROM   dual
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
SELECT 'RGLR' val,
       dt month_start,
       last_day(dt) month_end,
       'admin',
       SYSDATE,
       'admin',
       SYSDATE
FROM   dts;
```

Arguably, this is easier to read and follow than a recursive CTE, but you can do the same as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.men_txn ("VALUE", begin_date, end_date, created_by, created_date, modified_by, modified_date)
WITH dts (dt) AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                  FROM   dual
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT add_months(dt, 1)
                  FROM   dts
                  WHERE  add_months(dt, 1) <= add_months(to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 12))
SELECT 'RGLR' val,
       dt month_start,
       last_day(dt) month_end,
       'admin',
       SYSDATE,
       'admin',
       SYSDATE
FROM   dts;
```

N.B. I assume you're capable of working out how to specify a starting date and however many months you want to generate the list of dates for.

Also note, in Oracle, the DATE format contains time elements, so bear that in mind if you're using the dbo.men_txn table to compare to other dates - e.g. if you query for dates between 01/01/2022 and 31/01/2022, you will miss rows with dates after midnight on 31st Jan 2022.

Comment: I'm grateful you responded to my query. The answer was found.